# How to pass a form (Radio Button) data from child to parent onChange in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, event-handling, components

I want to pass the form data from the child component to the parent component I know it's easy to send the data using the event handler called onSubmit but I need this data to pass whenever the form gets change

So I tried to do it like this:
PS - This isn't my original code this is the code I write for practice this situation

App.js [Parent Component]

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';

function App() {

  function getData (data) {
      console.log (`coming from the parent component ${data}`)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form onSubmit={getData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Form.js [child Component]

```
import React from 'react';

function Form(props) {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const [answer, setAnswer] = React.useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
    setAnswer(event.target.value);
    props.onSubmit(answer);
  }

  console.log(answer);

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        <br />
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 1"
          name="paka"
        />{'Radio 1'}
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 2"
          name="paka"
        />{'Radio 2'}
        
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 3"
          name="paka"
        />{'Radio 3'}
        
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 4"
          name="paka"
        />{'Radio 4'}
        
        <br />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

so when I try to do it like this when I first press in radio child it's passes nothing. and when I press the another radio it's pass the previously pressed button

[This following image will be a example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCUgc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's one step behind is that you're using trying to use the state you *just set* as the handler argument but since the operation to update the state is batched and asynchronous that state isn't immediately available. The easiest way to solve the problem outlined *in this code* is to send the event value as the handler argument: `props.onSubmit(event.value)`.

The alternative would be to add a `useEffect` hook to watch for changes in the answer state and then call the submit handler:

```
useEffect(() => props.onSubmit(answer), [answer]);
```

A couple of further points which my updated working example incorporates.

1. Since you have just input elements you don't necessarily need a form element to wrap them.
2. For better accessibility use labels for your inputs. Identify which label corresponds with what input by adding an `htmlFor` attribute on the label, and an `id` attribute on the input.
3. It would be easier (and probably more meaningful) to call your handler `handleSubmit` to differentiate it from the element event handler called `onSubmit`.

```js
const { Fragment, useState } = React;

function App() {

  function handleSubmit(data) {
      console.log(`coming from the parent component ${data}`)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Form({ handleSubmit }) {
  
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setName(value);
    setAnswer(value);
    handleSubmit(value);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <section className="name">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </section>
      <section className="radios">
        <label htmlFor="radio1">Radio 1</label>
        <input
          id="radio1"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 1"
          name="paka"
        />
        <label htmlFor="radio2">Radio 2</label>
        <input
          id="radio2"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 2"
          name="paka"
        />
        <label htmlFor="radio3">Radio 3</label>
        <input
          id="radio3"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 3"
          name="paka"
        />
        <label htmlFor="radio4">Radio 4</label>
        <input
          id="radio4"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="radio"
          value="Radio 4"
          name="paka"
        />
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  );

}


const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.name label { margin-right: 0.25em; }
.radios label:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 0.5rem; } 
.radios { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How to reset the `Form data` from the parent in that case?

Comment: @CAVASINFlorian you should probably ask a new question for that with code that you're working with.